# Complex query in MySQL with multiple joins

Tags: mysql

Have been trying (unsuccessfully) to write a query with multiple joins, which is why I am now asking for your help.

**Table structure:**

- A parent which has many children and many cars
- A child which has one parent and many cars
- A car which **either** has one parent or one child.

[image: SQL Tables]
<sub>(source: [zxq.net](http://socialfork.zxq.net/img/sqlquery.jpg))</sub>

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to find to find the total value of the cars per parent. (A parent "owns" his childrens cars, so the sum of the value of the childrens cars should be added to the sum of the value of the parents cars).

For example, I want my query to return:

- If Thomas has a car worth 5000, and one child who has two cars also worth 5000, the total value for thomas is 5000 + 5000 * 2 = 15000.
- If John has two cars worth 2000, and two children who each have two cars worth 2000, the total value for John is : 2000 * 2 + 2000 * 2 + 2000 * 2 = 12000.

In short:

```
name   | total
--------------
Thomas | 15000
John   | 12000
```

**So far I have:**

```
SELECT p.name,
SUM(IFNULL(carparent.price, 0)+IFNULL(carchild.price, 0)) total
FROM parent p 

# first get the childrens cars
INNER JOIN child c ON c.parent_id = p.id
INNER JOIN car carchild ON carchild.child_id = c.id

# now get the parents cars
LEFT JOIN car carparent ON carparent.parent_id = p.id

GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Which is returning strange results when a parent has more than one child... I think I am getting confused with all the JOINS..

Anyways, if anyone could point me in the correct direction, I would be very grateful :)

Many thanks,

Comment: Could you just get rid of the parent table?

Comment: Does a Car record always have the parent_id filled in?

Comment: No, if the car is owned by the child, parent_id is null, and vice versa, if the car is owned by the parent, the child_id is null.

Comment: I would go for a totally different table structure here. Are you allowed to change the schemas, or you have to stick to them?

Comment: Yes I can change the table structure, what are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make your database as stated earlier.

Here is my solution.

```
select 
Name,
(select sum(price) 
    from car 
    where car.Parent_id=parent.id) as `Value Parent Car(s)`, 
(select sum(price) 
    from car 
    left join child 
    on car.child_id=child.id 
    where child.parent_id=parent.id) as `Value of Child car(s)`
from parent
```

Or to obtain a total

```
select 
id, 
Name,
((select sum(price) 
    from car 
    where car.Parent_id=parent.id) +
(select sum(price) 
    from car 
    left join child 
    on car.child_id=child.id 
    where child.parent_id=parent.id)) as `Total Value car(s)`
from parent
```

I am sure though that a better structure can be found... By example, a car is own by a person and a person can be a parent, a child or both...